# How to bind datatable with grid view without using bound and template fields in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
objRetailPL.branch = Request.QueryString["branch"].ToString();

objRetailPL.fromdate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["fromdate"].ToString());

objRetailPL.todate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["todate"].ToString());

DataTable dtget = new DataTable();

dtget = objRetailBAL.getWhReport(objRetailPL);

GVWHReport.DataSource = dtget;
```

I want to display datatable values in grid with out using bound fields and template fields. Directly from database to datatable and in grid. Because I am using pivot table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GridView has a [**`AutoGenerateColumns`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. Make sure it's set to `true`. **`This makes sure that bound fields are automatically created for each field in the data source`**.

Set the DataTable as the gridview's DataSource and call [**`DataBind()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method on GridView, something like:

```
MyGridView.DataSource = dtget;
MyGridView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 3):

**aspx page**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTest" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"></asp:GridView>
```

C# Code:

```
gvTest.DataSource = dtget;
gvTest.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your DataTable as DataSource and then invoke DataBind method on your GridView. Someting like this

```
GridView1.DataSource = dtget;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: i tried with that but it is showing empty grid.Actually there are records.

Comment: I thought AutoGenerateColumns property is set to true by default even if i don't specified it on design mode.